# how to fit cover videos in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, video, scale, clip

i trying to make a container with a video but of course its not possible to put full video in a dimension container, i try with fit, but even have errors, so i try with clip, here the solution for who wants:

if have a way using fit cover, someone???

the code with clip it here: and it works fine:

```
ClipRect(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity, \\ another size
          height: 400, \\another size
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Transform.scale( scale: 2,
            child: AspectRatio( aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller as VideoPlayerController)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 4):

try it, worked for me

```
SizedBox.expand(
  child: FittedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: SizedBox(
      height: _controller.value.size.height,
      width: _controller.value.size.width,
      child: VideoPlayer(
        _controller,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FittedBox` widget you can resize any child widget to fit inside the container:

```dart
Container(
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: AspectRatio( 
      aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
      child: VideoPlayer(_controller as VideoPlayerController),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: so, at this way, i tried many times, and given a message error! u already tested?

Comment: what is the error?